# generator-angular-fullstack - how to check for user permissions based on roles for certain routes

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mean-stack, angular-fullstack

I'm using generator-angular-fullstack and I would like to be able to add a new role of type: 'collaborator'.

Then check if the logged in user has the collaborator role before he/she can Delete or Update 'api/things'. However, if they want to Get or Create new things they would be able to do it with any other role.

I have been trying this in various different ways, but no luck.

Answer (score 2):

In your server/api/someAPI/index.js file add `auth.hasRole('collaborator')` as needed, like this:

```
router.get('/', controller.index);
router.post('/', controller.create);
router.put('/:id', auth.hasRole('collaborator'), controller.update);
router.delete('/:id', auth.hasRole('collaborator'), controller.destroy);
```

Then in your server/auth/auth.service.js make sure you have something like this:

```
function hasRole(roleRequired) {

  if (!roleRequired) {
    throw new Error('Required role needs to be set');
  }

  return (0, _composableMiddleware2.default)().use(isAuthenticated()).use(function meetsRequirements(req, res, next) {
    if (_environment2.default.userRoles.indexOf(req.user.role) <= _environment2.default.userRoles.indexOf(roleRequired)) {
      next();
    } else {
      res.status(403).send('Forbidden');
    }
  });
}
```